# Datetime не десериализируется

Tags: python, json, deserialize

у меня есть строка, которую нужно превратить в питоновский объект. Для этого я использую `json.loads`, но проблема в том, что в строке есть `datetime.datetime`, и он не десериализуется, как это можно поправить?

```
import json
json_string = '{"last_updated": {"$gte": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 19, 0, 0)}}'
dct = json.loads(json_string)
print(dct)
```

Тут вылетает ошибка

Comment: Вам нужен метод `strftime()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Так не подходит, потому что datetime.datetime сейчас это строка, а не объект

Comment: @Proksima, если это строка - значит у вас проблема с сериализацией, а не с десериализацией )

Comment: @MaxU Я сам не понял шутки, когда это увидел, но я сериализацию не могу поправить, так как файл уже сделан, да и в принципе не я писал сериализацию

Comment: @Proksima, тогда я пас - парсить заведомо сломанный JSON - очень неблагодарное дело

Comment: Ладно, всё равно спасибо, что посмотрели :)

Comment: @MaxU Можете пожалуйста тогда подсказать по другому поводу, я нашёл, как парсить datetime из строки, но теперь мне нужно, чтобы jsondecoder это делал, как это я могу сделать?

Comment: @Proksima, советую задать новый вопрос с соответствующим кодом и примерами

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Если вы уверены, что в текстовых полях (которые в кавычках) внутри json не могут встречаться такие же строки datetime.datetime(...) то предлагаю перед десериализацией найти с помощью регулярных выражений (модуль `re`) эти datetime и явно заменить их на даты в кавычках, как строки. после чего применить loads и после уже конвертировать строки внутри полученного питоновского объекта в datetime